# Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: java, image, swing, file-io, indexoutofboundsexception

in this program i m getting Array index out of bound exception, and i could not know where it is happening.This program retrieves the data from image already stored by some another program(Encrypt.java not explained here). thank you for your help

```
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.*;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.math.BigInteger;


public class Decrypt extends JFrame {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new Decrypt();
    }

    public Decrypt() throws Excenter code hereeption {
    setTitle("Color");
    setSize(300, 300);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(3);

    add(new PaintPanel(ImageIO.read(new File("src/outputImages/s2.bmp"))));
    setVisible(true);
    }

    class PaintPanel extends JPanel {

    /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private BufferedImage image;

    PaintPanel(BufferedImage image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        File file = new File("src/input.txt");
        int length=0, insertCounter;
        String strFileContent="";
        try {
        //create FileInputStream object
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream(file);

        /*
         * Create byte array large enough to hold the content of the file.
         * Use File.length to determine size of the file in bytes.
         */


        byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];

        /*
         * To read content of the file in byte array, use
         * int read(byte[] byteArray) method of java FileInputStream class.
         *
         */
        fin.read(fileContent);

        //create string from byte array
            strFileContent = new String(fileContent);

        System.out.println("File content : "+ strFileContent );

        BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(fileContent);
        // Format to binary
        strFileContent = bi.toString(2);      // 100100000111111110000
        length=strFileContent.length();      //thia variable contains the length of binary string
        //System.out.println(length+" File content in binary: "+ strFileContent );
        }
        catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("File not found" + e);
        }

        File file1 = new File("input.txt");
        byte outputBytes[] = new byte[(int)file1.length()];
        insertCounter=0;
        int localCounter=0;
        byte tempbyte=0x00;
        for (int h = 0; h <=image.getHeight()-3; h=h+3) {
        for (int w = 0; w <=image.getWidth()-3; w=w+3) {
            int whiteParity=0;
            for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<3;j++){
                int rgb = image.getRGB(w+j,h+ i);     
                if (rgb == -1)
                whiteParity++;
            }
            }
            /* if(WhitePArity==1 ||WhitePArity==3 ||WhitePArity==5 ||WhitePArity==7 ||WhitePArity==9){

               }*/

            if( image.getRGB(w+1,h+1)==-1){
            if(localCounter==0)
                tempbyte=(byte)(tempbyte|0x80);
            if(localCounter==1)
                tempbyte=(byte)(tempbyte|0x40);
            if(localCounter==2)
                tempbyte=(byte)(tempbyte|0X20);
            if(localCounter==3)
                tempbyte=(byte)(tempbyte|0x10);
            if(localCounter==4)
                tempbyte=(byte)(tempbyte|0x08);
            if(localCounter==5)
                tempbyte=(byte)(tempbyte|0x04);
            if(localCounter==6)
                tempbyte=(byte)(tempbyte|0x02);
            if(localCounter==7)
                tempbyte=(byte)(tempbyte|0x01);
            }
            localCounter++;

            if(localCounter==8){
            outputBytes[insertCounter]=tempbyte;
            insertCounter++;
            localCounter=0;
            tempbyte=(byte)(tempbyte & 0x00);
            }


        }

        String outputString=new String(outputBytes);
        String strFilePath = "output.txt";

        try{
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter(strFilePath);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            out.write(outputString);
            //Close the output stream
            out.close();
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("File not found" + e);
        }

        }

        g.drawImage(image, 0, 0, this);
    }
    }
}
```

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).  BTW `throws Excenter code hereeption {`  WTF?!? Is this Java?

Comment: You can put some System.out.println("") statements to see upto which line your code if fine and what line throws the error.

Comment: @AndrewThompson It is "enter code here" within the word "Exception": `Exc|enter code here|eption`

Answer (score 3):

I see two arrays in your code:

```
byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)file.length()];
```

and:

```
byte outputBytes[] = new byte[(int)file1.length()];
```

Both arrays are sized based on a call to `File.length()`

From the JavaDoc for [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/io/File.html):

> The length, in bytes, of the file denoted by this abstract pathname,
>   or 0L if the file does not exist. Some operating systems may return 0L
>   for pathnames denoting system-dependent entities such as devices or
>   pipes.

So my guess is that one of those files is either empty or does not exist.

(It would help diagnose the problem more decisively if you posted a complete stack trace, not just the exception message).